# Putting Deluge & SABnzbd behind an OpenVPN client

Tags: apache-http-server, openvpn, deluge

The setup on my Raspberry Pi is as follows:

- Apache webserver (mydomain.com)
- OpenVPN server (DNS based, also mydomain.com)
- Deluge (Apache reverse proxy mydomain.com/deluge/ & via Deluge ThinClient)
- SABnzbd (Apache reverse proxy mydomain.com/sabnzbd/)

My UFW rules:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
sudo ufw limit from 172.16.0.0/24 to any port 22      # ssh local network
sudo ufw limit from 10.8.0.0/24 to any port 22        # ssh vpn users
sudo ufw allow from 172.16.0.0/24 to any port 58846   # deluge thinclient local network
sudo ufw allow from 10.8.0.0/24 to any port 58846     # deluge thinclient vpn users
sudo ufw allow out 53                                 # dns requests
sudo ufw allow in 80                                  # apache
sudo ufw allow out 80                                 # apt, wget, etc.
sudo ufw allow in 443                                 # apache
sudo ufw allow out 443                                # apt, wget, etc.
sudo ufw allow 1194                                   # vpn (opendns)
```

My router port forwards:

```
80, 443, 1194
```

In other words, the webserver & OpenVPN server are accessible from outside my network. SSH & Deluge ThinClient only if you're connected to the OpenVPN server or in the local network.

It's all working as of the moment. But, I want to let the Deluge & SABnzbd connection go via VPN. I already have a VPN available and the necessary .openvpn config file.

How would I proceed in getting the Deluge & SABnzbd downloads to go over the VPN connection while keeping the Apache webserver available (including the reverse proxy to Deluge & SABnzbd) and the OpenVPN server?

In other words, how can I use OpenVPN client only for Deluge & SABnzbd downloads?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get this working so I settled with a Docker container. [This](https://github.com/binhex/arch-deluge) one for anyone interested.